# Como criar email em Swift usando MFMailComposerController corretamente?

Tags: ios, swift, email, delegate

Estou tendo problemas ao criar um email com `MFMailComposerController` em Swift. Ao tentar atribuir `self` a `emailController.mailComposerController` recebo um erro informando que não posso atribuir `TelaFinalViewController (self)` para um valor do tipo `MFMailComposerViewController`.

Escrevi o seguinte código abaixo:

```
// Teste para possibilidade de envio
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){

            // Criação do Email
            let emailController:MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

            emailController.mailComposeDelegate = self // Ocorre o erro aqui!
            emailController.setSubject(assunto)
            emailController.setToRecipients([para])
            emailController.setMessageBody(corpoEmail, isHTML: false)

// Demais implementação ...

        }
```

Mensagem de erro:

> Cannot assign a value of type "TelaFinalViewController" to a value of
>   type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate!'

Procurei em tutoriais e aqui mesmo no Stackoverflow, mas não achei especificamente este uma solução ou explicação para este problema.

Seria um caso de bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certifique-se que sua classe `TelaFinalViewController` implementa o protocolo `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`.

Exemplo como a definição de sua classe deve ficar:

```
 class TelaFinalViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

Comment: Perfeito, so fiz a alteração da sintaxe. Obrigado!